# How do I implement a function that reads each bit of a variable?

Tags: c, bitmask

The output of printBits('A') suppose to be 0100 0001 but I'm getiing 0100 0001 0100 1101 0000 0000. I can't seem to figure out the problem in my code below.

```
unsigned char getBit(unsigned char c, int n) {
  return c=(c&(1<<n))>>n;

}


void printBits(unsigned char c) {
  int i=7;
  while(i>=0){
    printf("%d", (getBit(c,i--);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to get bit `n` of a value `c`, why not just do `(c >> n) & 1`?

Comment: also, why does your method return `char`? It would be more logic if it returned a `bool` value.

Comment: Is this cut and paste from your actual code? It doesn't compile.

Comment: take into account that `'0'` is not `0`, but `48` (ASCII code)

Comment: It is meant to return an unsigned char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output seems to match your input just fine, but your output shows you called your print function two more times. The output matches this sequence of calls:

```
printBits('A');
printBits('M');
printBits('\0');
```

This is shown [here](http://ideone.com/zxwmbh) (after fixing a syntax error in your print function).

Comment: Sorry, but I can't seem to see the difference between your printBit() function and mine

Comment: Yes. The point of my answer is that I provided a program that produces the exact same output that you reported.

Comment: ok,so what can I do to prevent my function from being called two more times?

Comment: You don't show your whole program that produced what you thought was bad output, so I can't advise on that.